# Inversion is not used after "not far/long"

Tags: grammar, negation, subject-verb-inversion

Page 271 of Practical English Usage reads

> Inversion is not used after "**not far/long**" so we say *Not far from
> here you can see foxes*, or
> *Not long after that she got married*

Why don't these phrases trigger inversion like similar *negative and restrictive expressions* as in *Not a single word did he say*?

Answer (score 4):

The negation in sentences like “Not a single word did he say” applies to the clause level; rearranged, it is “He **did not say** a single word”.

The negation in the examples without inversion is not at the clause level: “Not far from here you can see foxes” doesn't mean “You cannot see foxes far from here”.

“Not long after that she got married” would probably not be expressed by “She did not get married long after that” (I can maybe barely imagine it if you put stress on *long* are are trying to emphasize that she did *not* get married long after).

I think the inversion associated with negative expressions only occurs when the negation semantically applies at the clause level.

I'm not sure my explanation is correct. There is no problem with saying *He did not hit the ball very far* and *She did not stay in the house very long,* with negation at the clause level.

So if *Not very far did he hit the ball and *Not for very long did she stay in the water are ungrammatical, it's for a different reason.

To me, "Far from here(,) you can see foxes" and "Long after that(,) she got married" sound grammatical, although I'm not certain. ("Far from here" and "long after that" definitely aren't as commonly encountered at the start of a sentence as their negated equivalents.)

Comment: Right. Basically, some adverbials (of time, place, and circumstance) are not optional; everything that takes place does so at a certain time and place and under certain circumstances. Negating these adverbs thus negates the entire sentence, and that licenses fronting with inversion. Other adverbs (manner, intent, means, instrument, etc.) are optional and their negation has no effect on the assertion of the sentence. Hence, since fronting with inversion is an NPI, it's not allowed with these. [More details here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/anyquestions.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler What about _not very far_ and _not for long_?

Comment: Very often, the inversion is triggered by the preposing of a PP or other element, as in the "Not a single word did he say" example. Likewise in, for example, "In no city has she been entirely comfortable".

Comment: *_Not very far did he hit the ball_ and *_Not for very long did she stay in the water_ are both ungrammatical because they don't negate.  He **did** hit the ball, and she **did** stay in the water for a little while.

Comment: @JohnLawler What about _**No longer** were they isolated from each other_?

Comment: _No longer_ means 'not at any later time' so they were **not** isolated from each other.
The adverb is one of time, place, or circumstance, and entails negation of the entire clause, hence inversion is allowed.

Comment: @JohnLawler "**Not only** must come first when you are linking two clauses which have different subjects: _Not only were the locals all old, but the women stiff dressed in long black dresses_" https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Not+only+were+the+locals+all+old,+but+the+women%22&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiRobWkz5HrAhX7QhUIHdvsDqYQ_AUoAXoECAIQCQ&biw=1366&bih=653

Comment: @JohnLawler The scope of the negative is only the adjective: at some distance from here - what distance? - not far from here. It doesn't negate 'from here' or 'after that', just the quantification. However, in 'not a single word' the negation includes 'word' - he didn't say any words - it isn't "not a single word, but several words". So inversion is used **when the whole phrase is negative**, but not when the fronted phrase is positive but includes a negative quantifier.

Comment: @JohnLawler what about **restrictive experssions**, as in _Only after her death was I able to appreciate her_ Is it also a negative quantifier?

Comment: _Only_ is a negative quantifier. _Only Bill saw anything_ means that no one except Bill saw anything. _Only after her death_ means not before her death.